# how to display json in table vuejs

Tags: json, vue.js, vuex

how to display the following json data ?
i have json data like this, and want to display it in table, i use  vue-bostrapt .
Previously I tried like this, but it's not perfect.

this my json

```
[
    {
      "id":"1",
      "name": "KINTIL",
      "desc": "Kintil is good",
      "location": [
        {
        "prov": "Jawa Barat",
        "city": "Bandung"
        },
        {
        "prov": "Banten",
        "city": "Tanggerang"
        }
      ],
      "applied": [
        {
            "item_name": "galian"
        },
        {
            "item_name": "timbunan"
        }
      ],
      "exception": [
        {
            "ex_name": "F001",
            "ex_value": "001001"
        },
        {
            "ex_name": "M001",
            "ex_value": "002002"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

and this html

```
<b-table class="table spacing-table" style="font-size: 13px;" show-empty 
    :items="inovasi" :fields="fields" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="0" :filter="filter" >
</b-table>
```

and this my script

```
import json from "../static/data.json";
export default {
  name: 'tes',
    data() {
    return {
        inovasi:[],
        filter: null,
        fields: [
         {
            key: 'id',
            label: 'id',
            sortable: true
         },
         {
            key: 'name',
            label: 'name',
            sortable: true
         },
         {
            key: 'location',
            label: 'location',
            sortable: true
         },
         {
            key: 'applied',
            label: 'applied',
            sortable: true
         },
         { key: 'actions', label: 'Doc' }
         ],
         currentPage: 0,
         perPage: 5,
         totalItems: 0
      }
  },
  mounted() {
     this.inovasi = json;
  },
  computed:{
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
```

this result
[image]

how to display location and applied , into a single row table ?
thanks in advance for those who have answered :)

thanks

Comment: Which parameter(prov or city) do you want to show for location record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [formatter](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#formatter-callback) like

```
fields: [
   {
      key: 'id',
      label: 'id',
      sortable: true
   },
   {
      key: 'name',
      label: 'name',
      sortable: true
   },
   {
      key: 'location',
      label: 'location',
      sortable: true,
      formatter: (value, key, item) => { 
         return value.map(x => 'prov: ' + x.prov + ' city:' + x.city).join(", ") 
      }
   },
   {
      key: 'applied',
      label: 'applied',
      sortable: true,
      formatter: (value, key, item) => { 
         return value.map(x => x.item_name).join(", ") 
      }
   },
   { key: 'actions', label: 'Doc' }
],
```

It will show for the location column this: `prov: Jawa Barat city:Bandung, prov: Banten city:Tanggerang` and for the applied column this: `galian, timbunan`